# in which scenarios onDestroy() is not called?

Tags: android

I know that In Android, you won't get a guaranteed activity's `onDestroy()` call. My question is in which scenarios onDestroy() is not called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there are two activities A and B.Activity A contains a next button and B contains a back button.If you click next,then Activity B will be launched.At that point of time **onDestroy() is not called**.onStop() of activity A is called after onResume() of B.

Then when you click the back button in Activity B,**then onRestart() of A** will called after onStop() of B.In this case also onDestroy() will be not called.

When you press the back button **of the device onDestroy() will be called at that point of time** or if you call **finish()** while navigating from A to B.

Answer (score 4):

The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space.